# Is it possible install Python modules in my system when Canopy's Python is the default?

Tags: python, macos, bash, enthought, canopy

**OSX**. When I installed the Canopy IDE, *Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.6* was set as the default Python for the bash shell:

```
$ python
Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.6 | 32-bit | (default, Sep 15 2014, 17:36:57) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Currently, I am using another IDE (*PyCharm*) for a project where a Python module is needed. I tried to download the module directly from the bash shell using *pip* but it did not work:

```
pip install psycopg2 <---module
```

I believe it has something to do with *Enthought Canopy Python* running, so I attempted to restore the original python. However, I could not restore it. The instructions from this Enthought post (2011) did not work:

[OS X - After EPD installation, restore system python to be default](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204470100-OS-X-After-EPD-installation-restore-system-python-to-be-default)

They say to comment out the following lines from the ~/.bash_profile file, save the changes and restart the bash shell:

```
# PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
# export PATH
```

Didn't work.

Comment: What is the output of running ``which python`` from Terminal?

Comment: The SO post you are referring to is for EPD, not Canopy.

Comment: Instead, see https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy

Comment: @pzp /Users/me/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/bin/python

Comment: @JonathanMarch thank, I was able to unset it and install the module I needed.